# localhost в wordpress, какой реальный адрес сервера?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

В wp-config.php указан DB_HOST как localhost. Также пароль, имя пользователя и прочее. А к какому серверу конектится на самом деле wordpress? Чтобы я также мог к нему подключиться написав в адресной сроке браузера соответствующий адрес.

Comment: В браузере — никак, база данных же не использует ни хттп, ни веб-странички

Comment: @andreymal  можно и не в браузере, а вообще как-то получить доступ и есть ли такая возможность если нет доступа к фтп и в панель хостинга?

Comment: А это зависит от настроек базы; если подключения извне разрешены, то достаточно подключиться любым клиентом к айпишнику сервера по порту 3306, а если не разрешены, то никак

Comment: @andreymal по 3306 не работает, это значит что запрещено? или по другому порту может конектиться?

Answer (score 2):

Тот же самый хост, на котором сайт.

Например, адрес сайта `site.org`, значит, и подключаться надо к `site.org`.

Только непонятно, как вы собираетесь к нему подключаться из браузера. Вам нужен phpmyadmin, который должен быть установлен на том же сервере.

На самом деле localhost как раз для того, чтобы нельзя было подключиться извне к базе. В случае phpmyadmin вы подключаетесь к нему, а он внутри сервера - к базе.

Comment: подключаюсь добавив порт 3306, но не работает. А если просто перейти на адрес сайта, то выводит собственно сам сайт.

Comment: 3306 - это phpmyadmin

Comment: я так понимаю что получить доступ к базе можно либо по фтп, так как wordpress же его получает, либо через панель хостинга. Если нет доступа к панели и к фтп, то и к базе доступа тоже нет?

Comment: По ftp к базе получить доступ нельзя. WordPress делает запросы к mySQL внутри сервера. Если доступа к панели нет, то и к phpmyadmin, скорее всего, доступа нет. Настройки хостинга/сервера могут быть самые разные, вариантов много. Но если shared hosting, то вряд ли. Однако на beget можно так: https://ваш-сервер-на-beget.beget.com/phpMyAdmin/index.php

Comment: почему по фтп нельзя, можно в wordpress подправить код, который удалит базу. Ведь в нем можно спокойно любые запросы выполнять.

Comment: это уже доступ к файлам .php wordpress, а уже посредством кода в них - к базе. Это не доступ к базе как таковой.

Comment: да согласен, но факт в том что таким образом можно получить доступ к базе и ее испоганить, а мне это как раз не нужно. Если нет доступа к панели и к фтп, то надеюсь не смогут получить доступ к базе.

Comment: Общее правило таково: если есть доступ к ftp на модификацию, то можно сделать с WP все: завести нового админа, испортить базу и т.д.